# IF statement inside a function to get value from an ACF field

Tags: php, wordpress, advanced-custom-fields, shortcode, code-snippets

I'm trying to create custom function in WordPress with ACF, and use it as a shortcode.

What I want to do is quite simple:

- Get a field from ACF
- Check if the text is "not found" or something else
- If it's something else, I'll show an H2 and a sentence with field content.
- If its "not found" I don't want to show anything

I tried various code, here's my last one:

```
// write a shortcode that creates a text if the field is not "not found"

function show_alliance() {
    $alliance = get_field('field_6383d4b46deed');

    if ($alliance !='not found'): {
        return '<h2>TITLE</h2><p>This is... '. $alliance .' </p>';
    }
    else: {
        return '';}
    }

add_shortcode('alliance', 'show_alliance')
```

By WordPress always comes up with errors when I save my snippet. I can't find a way to make it work.

(I use Code Snippets in WordPress)

Any ideas?
(I'm sure it's very simple...)

--

Tried different syntax, but WordPress never validates the code snippet.

Last one is:

`L’extrait de code que vous essayez d’enregistrer a produit une erreur fatale à la ligne 11 :

syntax error, unexpected '}'`

When I delete the } to put it a the end it tells me that I should not have it there...

Answer (score 0):

Please try this code I think this is working fine.

```
**PHP Code**

<?php if(get_field('field_6383d4b46deed')){ ?><h2>TITLE</h2><p>This is... '. $alliance .' </p>
else ?>
echo' ';
<?php } ?>
```

Comment: This has broken my wordpress...
"There has been a critical error on your website..."

Answer (score 0):

Here's the answer that works :

```
function show_alliance() {
    $alliance = get_field('field_6383d4b46deed');
    if ($alliance !='not found') {
        return '<h2>TITLE</h2><p>This is... '. $alliance .' </p>';
    }
    else {
        return '';
    }
}
add_shortcode('alliance', 'show_alliance');
```